# Twilio API for making outbound calls with a speech stream

Tags: twilio, node-red, twilio-api, watson

I have a scenario where say at 5.00 AM every morning, I have a server side script / batch job that wakes up, selects a phone number from a list based on an algorithm, places a call to that phone number and uses text-to-speech to deliver a customized message. I have 2 questions,

1. Which Twilio API can I use to achieve this? Bear in mind there is no app UI and all the code would be on the back end. Think NodeRED flow or a Python script that is made to run at a given time.
2. Instead of specifying the text in the TwiML, can I pass say an audio stream from Watson's Text to Speech to the appropriate Twilio API?

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you would need to use the programmable voice API from Twilio. This lets you play audio files, text to speech, make and manipulate phone calls, etc. I have never used Watson Text-to-Speech, but, if it can output an audio file you can play that with Twilio TwiML.

Here's an example in Node.

```
npm install twilio

//require the Twilio module and create a REST client
var client = require('twilio')('ACCOUNT_SID', 'AUTH_TOKEN');

client.makeCall({

to:'+16515556677', // Any number Twilio can call
from: '+14506667788', // A number you bought from Twilio
url: 'url/to/twiml/which/may/have/WatsonURL' // A URL that produces TwiML

}, function(err, responseData) {

    //executed when the call has been initiated.
    console.log(responseData.from); // outputs "+14506667788"

});
```

The TwiML could look like this:

```
<Response>
    <Play loop="1">https://api.twilio.com/cowbell.mp3</Play>
</Response>
```

This would play the cowbell sound from the Twilio API. Just a default sound. This could be easily generated to play a Watson sound file if you can get a URL for that.

You could do the same thing in Node, if you'd rather not build the XML manually.

```
var resp = new twilio.TwimlResponse();

resp.say('Welcome to Twilio!')
    .pause({ length:3 })
    .say('Please let us know if we can help during your development.', {
        voice:'woman',
        language:'en-us'
    })
    .play('http://www.example.com/some_sound.mp3');
```

If you were to take this toString() it would output formatted XML (TwiML):

```
console.log(resp.toString());
```

This outputs:

```
<Response>
    <Say>Welcome to Twilio!</Say>
    <Pause length="3"></Pause>
    <Say voice="woman" language="en-us">Please let us know if we can help during your development.</Say>
    <Play>http://www.example.com/some_sound.mp3</Play>
</Response>
```

Hopefully this clears it up for you.

Scott

Comment: Thanks for offering such a detailed response Scott! Can we send you a t-shirt? Email mspeir@twilio.com for details.

Comment: Thanks Megan. I sent you an email.